# I want my smart contract to work with USDT

Tags: javascript, solidity, contract, trx, tronweb

Im implementing a smart contract but i want every payable transaction work with USDT. My contract is working fine but its working with TRX.

Im using tronweb to interact with it from FrontEnd.

I tried using `tokenid:` on send parameter, but i found that it only works for TRC10.

```
await Utils.contract
      .registerUserFE("TNBDbRe....T2RHnSW")
      .send({
        feeLimit: 800000,
        tokenId: 1002968,
        shouldPollResponse: true,
      }).then(result =>console.log("result: " + result))
      .catch(error => console.log("error: " + error));
```